# Generate and maintain documentation from java code

Tags: java

Any idea?
How can I generate documentation using already present code in java class / classes. As the java class changes, I would want it to reflect in documentation automatically.

Regards
Monica Soni

Comment: "*As the java class changes, I would want it to reflect in documentation automatically*" what kind of changes do you mean and how it should affect documentation? Could you provide some examples?

Comment: what is the java edition ? EE ? spring se ? please specify

Comment: For the how: javadoc. For the automated checking: not possible. There are simply no working solutions to automatically detect whether the code documentation fully and correctly reflects the code content. It is the responsibility of the developer to be always exercise due diligence to keep code and documentation in sync.

Answer (score 2):

There are some tools available on the market that scan your code and generate a documentation for it. A known tool which does it, and my favourite, is [Javadoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc). It also allows you to add annotations to the code which later be reflected in the documentation.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20875212)

Comment: @Nic3500 - true, I'll fix it (: